# What is the complexity for the BFS algotithm for shortest path on unweighted grid?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

What is the complexity of the BFS algorithm for the shortest path on the unweighted grid?

The grid is a classical maze with a starting point and exit, need to find an exit.  Can move only vertically and horizontally.

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901203/dfs-and-bfs-time-and-space-complexities-of-number-of-islands-on-leetcode#:%7E:text=The%20way%20I%20see%20it,cols

Comment: What does *unweighted grid* mean? If each length is zero, all paths have length zero. If every "point on a rectangular grid" is connected to each of its axis-parallel neighbours by an edge of length 1, the length of every shortest path is the Manhattan distance - no search called for. (There is a mildly irritating typo in the title.)

Comment: It is like a classical maze, you have a starting point, need to find an exit. No weights, so we can use BFS, but what is complexity? BFS standard is O(V+E), but I saw some sources state that it is O(V) here, just don't understand why?

Comment: Don't tell me: [edit the question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ogbofjnr in standard BFS applied to undirected graph we might not know how much graph is dense. If it is density is "each to each" then it is O(V^2). In the grid it is known that each vertex has  4 out-coming edges. Thus  tilde ~ notation complexity is 4 * V + V which is O(V) asymptotic complexity  to within a constant factor.